# Cron job doesn't work (with docker command)

Tags: cron

I have some commands I want to run every day in my crontab:

```
5 0 * * * docker image prune
5 0 * * * docker image prune -a
5 0 * * * docker container prune
```

They don't seem to be really working as my server memory keeps decreasing with the amount of images and containers stocked. I know those commands takes a manual intervention to accept with y, I tried the docker image prune -y in my terminal but it is not getting recognized.

Any tip? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `-f` flag:

```
docker image prune -a -f
```

Help text:

```
Usage:  docker image prune [OPTIONS]

Remove unused images

Options:
  -a, --all     Remove all unused images, not just dangling ones
  -f, --force   Do not prompt for confirmation
      --help    Print usage
```

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to run command in cron. So, Here some step

1. Create a bash script to run whatever command you need like in scheduler:-
   filename :- cronjob.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
docker image prune -a -f
```

2. Now call this cronjob.sh into you cron for scheduler whatever time you need. For this type in terminal:-

```
# crontab -e
```

3. Go to end of file and add you file location with its predefined syntax :-

```
* * * * bash YOUR_FILE_LOCATION/crontab.sh (# execute every minute)
```

Comment: Just change in script whatever command you like to run or test.